# gnome-session-flashback : Desktop icons disappear after opening File Explorer

Tags: desktop-environments, gnome-session-fallback

I have been using `gnome-session-flashback` package for some time now and it has never caused this issue before but i have just got a new machine with Ubuntu 14 LTS on it and when i installed this package it would stop showing desktop icons when i open new instance of File Explorer.

Every time i run this command they show up but disappear when i open file explorer:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true`

I also tried setting it from dconf-editor although i think both are same and with the same effect.

Comment: I inspected the file explorer link that would make my desktop disappear and i found out that it had --no-desktop command parameter with it. I removed that and it does not remove my icons anymore. But the icon of file explorer changed from folder to something weird.

Answer (score 2):

So if anyone is having this issue, it's because his Nautilus is opening up with `--no-desktop` flag. Most probably it's an icon or link created by yourself and upon editing it's properties you can remove the flag to make it work so that desktop icons don't disappear anymore.

Comment: Please add the terminal commands needed to complete the task you described.  It might get you some upvotes.

Comment: you just saved my day

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-flashback.desktop show-icons true
```